# array_push without keys modification?

Tags: php, arrays

For example if I have `$a=array('a','b','c','d')` and make `unset($a[0])`, array becomes

```
Array
(
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => d
)
```

and if I make `$a[]='e'`, this array becomes

```
Array
(
[0] => b
[1] => c
[2] => d
[3] => e
)
```

(resets keys)

but I need that it stay to look like

```
Array
(
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => d
[4] => d
)
```

How to achieve this with minimum of code, if it's possible, of course?

**EDIT:**

sorry, guys

There was `array_splice()` in the middle of my code. Sorry for my awkward question

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Can you explain?

Comment: why cant you just `$a[4] = 'a';`??

Comment: from where came the seconde d ?do you want to rotate your array ?

Comment: `$a=array('a','b','c','d'); unset($a[0]); $a[]='e';` will give you `array(4) {
  [1] =>
  string(1) "b"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "c"
  [3] =>
  string(1) "d"
  [4] =>
  string(1) "e"
}`. There is no keys reset.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk is right actually and here's a [demo](http://codepad.org/NZwr6Atf).

Comment: @Alexander Yancharuk yeah you're right. There was `array_splice()` in the middle of my code. Sorry for my awkward question =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't find useful simply `$arr[] =` approach, I believe this is enough minimum of code to get done what you're doing

```
<?php

$arr = array('b','c','d');

unset($arr[0]);

end($arr);
$arr[key($arr)+1] = 'e';

var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Notice that this will only work if you know that this array will take only numeric keys.

Alternative way would be

```
$arr[end(array_keys($arr))+1] = 'e';
```

instead of

```
end($arr);
$arr[key($arr)+1] = 'e';
```